# Error java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean

Tags: react-native

After adding Swipeable to the component, now I'm getting this Error.
I'm using expo go on android, everything is working fine. but adding Swipeable to the component now I'm getting this error.

**Error Image is attched**
[image]

**Component Code**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet,Image, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';


import colors from '../config/colors';
import Swipeable from "react-native-gesture-handler/Swipeable";
import AppText from './AppText';

function ListItem({title, subTitle, image, onPress,renderRightActions}) {
    return (
      <Swipeable renderRightActions={renderRightActions}>
        <TouchableHighlight underlayColor={colors.light} onPress={onPress}>
          <View style={styles.listContainer}>
              <Image style={styles.image} source={image}/>
              <View>
                  <AppText style={styles.title}>{title}</AppText>
                  <AppText style={styles.subTitle}>{subTitle}</AppText>
              </View>
          </View>
          </TouchableHighlight>
       </Swipeable>
    );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  listContainer:{
    flexDirection:'row',
    padding:15
  } ,
  image:{
    width:70,
    height:70,
    borderRadius:35,
    marginRight:10
  },
  title:{
    fontWeight:'600'
  },
  subTitle:{
    color:colors.medium
  }
})
export default ListItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping Swipeable component in a GesterHandlerRootView

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).